# How to have relationship in Laravel 5.7 based on a json data key saved in a table column?

Tags: json, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.7

I am using this [Staudenmein package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations) in Laravel and referring to this answer given by the package owner himself.

I have two tables, `pets` and `notifications` with models `Pet` and `Notification`.
The `notifications` table has a column called `data` which is of JSON dataType and stores JSON data

```
{"pet_id":"4","pet_type_id":1,"lost_report_id":3,"pet_sighting_id":21,"latitude":"22.676846","longitude":"88.338509"}
```

The key `pet_id` denotes the `id` column of the `pets` table. I need a relationship so that I can fetch the name of the pet from `pets` table.

By referring to the answer link given above, I wrote my `Notification` model like this:-

```
namespace App\Models;

use DB, App, Auth, Hash, Lang, Mail, Config, Exception, Validator, Globals;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

use App\User;
use App\Models\AdminConfig;
use App\Models\ReceivedAppNotification;

class Notification extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
           'data' => 'json'
        ];

    public function notificationPet()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pet', 'data->pet_id');
    }
}
```

When I am running the query like this:-

```
$notificationQuery = Notification::with('notificationPet')
                             ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('$userId', in_app_notification_receiver)")
                             ->where(array(
                                  'status'     => Globals::SMALL_CHAR_ACTIVE,
                                  'is_delete'  => Globals::SMALL_CHAR_NO,
                               ))->get()->toArray();
```

I get the notificationPet relationship as empty, ie. the data-set is like this:-

```
Array
(
    [id] => 10
    [title] => 
    [message] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [pet_id] => 4
            [latitude] => 22.676846
            [longitude] => 88.338509
            [pet_type_id] => 1
            [lost_report_id] => 3
            [pet_sighting_id] => 34
        )

    [no_of_in_app_notification_receiver] => 2
    [no_of_push_notification_receiver] => 1
    [from_user] => 22
    [in_app_notification_receiver] => 2,23
    [push_notification_receiver] => 2
    [status] => a
    [is_delete] => n
    [push_notification_sent] => n
    [created_date] => 2020-03-19 13:23:17
    [modified_date] => 2020-03-19 13:23:17
    [created_at] => 2020-03-19 13:23:17
    [updated_at] => 2020-03-19 13:23:17
    [notification_pet] => 
)
```

However, I have a record in pets table with id = 4, already. So the relationship should not be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

#### Change:

```
 protected $casts = [
           'data' => 'json'
        ];
```

#### To:

```
 protected $casts = [
           'data' => 'array'
        ];
```

Comment: it still comes the same, empty relationship

Comment: @Saswat can you make sure if `pet_id` is an int in your data field?

Comment: Changed the json data to {"pet_id": 4, "latitude": "22.676846", "longitude": "88.338509", "pet_type_id": 1, "lost_report_id": 3, "pet_sighting_id": 21}, still its coming empty